# Help needed with upgrading bitcoin ABC

Tags: bitcoin-cash, daemon

I'm running my own bitcoin cash node. However, I'm getting stuck on the block where the network hard forked for the May 15th 32mb blocksize update. I believe the version of bitcoin abc I have installed is out of date, hence why it is stuck at block 530361. Here is the version with getinfo:

```
{
  "version": 160200,
  "protocolversion": 70015,
}
```

Is my node out of date? How can I upgrade my bitcoin abc node?

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but nothing changes in the version or protocol version with `getinfo`. What should I do?

Comment: How did you install bitcoin-abc in the first place?

Comment: @NateEldredge I forgot how I originally installed it, awhile ago.

Comment: you can try `apt list --installed | grep bitcoin` to see if it was installed by `apt-get`. If not, then `apt-get upgrade` won't work. chances are you downloaded from https://download.bitcoinabc.org/ or built it from source. you should back up your wallet data file before any upgrade though.

Comment: For future readers: the Bitcoin-ABC client is (confusingly) not a Bitcoin client.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to upgrade.  You have version 0.16.2, and the 32MB block support was added in 0.17.0.  The latest release version is 0.17.2.

Your `apt-get` commands will only work if you originally installed bitcoin-abc from the [apt package repository](https://launchpad.net/~bitcoin-abc/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).  It sounds like you didn't.

You can check if you installed from a package at all with `dpkg -l bitcoinabc`.  If so then you can remove the package with `dpkg -r bitcoinabc`.  Otherwise you can figure out where the bitcoin-abc binaries are installed (using `which` or similar) and delete them manually.  Then install a new copy from scratch, either from the above-linked repository or any other way you choose.  (But this time make a note of what you did!)

Comment: dpkg -l bitcoinabc finds no packages, so yes I believe I installed from source. I want to install new copy from the repo, so I added ppa:bitcoin-abc/ppa. How can I specify the package I want though? apt-get install (name), but it says not found for every name I try. (already ran apt-get update after adding the repo)

Comment: Should just be called `bitcoinabc`, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @2523454: What Linux distribution / version is this?

Comment: 0.14.04, I'm trying 0.16 now

Comment: No package found when running apt-get install bitcoinabc on both versions.

Comment: Hm.  What exactly got added to /etc/apt/sources.list.d?  When you did apt-get update, did you see it fetching the Packages file for the repo?  Any error messages?

Comment: Taking a look at sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list, I see nothing bitcoin related. Here is my console after adding the repo: https://imgur.com/a/tIhYyx5

Comment: I have updated by manually compiling and installing the latest source code.

Comment: add-apt-repository normally adds a new file in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` subdirectory instead of modifying  `/etc/apt/sources.list`.  Anyway, glad you got it working.